# What is the difference in the following JS syntax?

Tags: javascript

Following are two ways to define BW.Timer.  Can someone tell me what the difference is?  I am not certain the first is even valid, but if it is valid, what is different about using the `myfunc=(function(){}())` syntax?

```
BW.Timer = (function () {
    return {
        Add: function (o) {
            alert(o);
        },
        Remove: function (o) {
            alert(o);
        }
    };
} ());
```

And...

```
BW.Timer = function () {
    return {
        Add: function (o) {
            alert(o);
        },
        Remove: function (o) {
            alert(o);
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: those two snippets are not equivalent - the top assigns the return from an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to `BW.Timer`, the bottom just assigns a function (the same function that is immediately executed in the first example) to `BW.Timer`.

Comment: Have you done any basic logging of the result? If you do, you'll see that the first is indeed valid, and that they have a different result. There are hundreds of questions on StackOverflow that deal with that function syntax.

Comment: The first snippet uses an [immediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) or "IIFE".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first is the return-value of the immediately-invoked function. The second is a function. It essentially comes down to what the difference is between these:

```
var f = (function() { return 0; })();

var f = function() { return 0; };
```

Since the first function is called immediately, the value of 0 is given to the variable `f`. The first `f` is not a function. However, the second `f` we must call in order to get the value:

```
f(); // 0
```

It follows that in your example, the first `BW.Timer` is the object literal itself and the second is a function returning an object literal. You must call the function in order to get to the object:

```
BW.Timer().Add(x);
```

### Why use the first then?

You might ask yourself why one would use a syntax like `a = (function() { return {}; })()` instead of `a = {}`, but there's a good reason. An IIFE (Immeditately-Invoked Function Expression), unlike a regular function allows the emulation of static variables (variables that maintain their value through a single instance). For example:

```
var module = (function() {
    var x = 0;

    return {   get: function()  { return x },
               set: function(n) { x = n }
    };

})();
```

The above a text-book example of the [Module Pattern](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/). Since the function is called right away, the variable `x` is instantiated and the return value (the object) is given to `module`. There's no way we can get to `x` other than by using the `get` and `set` methods provided for us. Therefore, `x` is static, meaning its variable won't be overridden each time you use `module`.

```
module.set(5);

module.get(); // 5
```

On the other hand, let's see an example where `module` is declared as a function instead:

```
// assume module was made as a function

module().set(5);

module().get(); // 0
```

When we call `module()` the `x` variable is overridden each time. So we're effectively using different instances of `module` and `x` each time we call `module`.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is rather large.

In the first case, `BW.Timer` is executed when it is first encountered, and that is the static version assigned to `BW.Timer`. In that instance, `BW.Timer.Add(1)` may be used. Each call to `BW.Timer` will be the same object.

In the second case, `BW.Timer` is not executed when first encountered, and instead is a function referece which must be invoked `BW.Timer()`.  For `Add` to be used, this must be the case `BW.Timer().Add(1)`. Also, you can issue `var timer = new BM.Timer();`. Each instance of `BW.Timer()` will be unique here.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example `BW.Timer` references an object that the self-executing function returns, while in the second example it references a function object, in other words it's a function that can be executed `BW.Timer()`.